# Can we hack CORS support for custom APEX Rest services (without a proxy)?

Tags: rest-service, cross-domain, apexrest

I thought not, until I saw this post [How do I open up a public REST API to JavaScript in any website?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34379/how-do-i-open-up-a-public-rest-api-to-javascript-in-any-website)  (and tweet https://twitter.com/metadaddy/status/453026655892545536) by Pat.

Pardon my denseness but wouldn't that require access to something like an @HttpOptions annotation in custom APEX REST, in order to reply to the preflight CORS check?

Otherwise I guess my option is this little solution http://www.jamesward.com/2014/06/23/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-for-salesforce-com

Comment: Please vote up this Idea on salesforce ideas so we can get cors: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000lBEZAA2

Answer (score 5):

Any apex class can be exposed by using Site in Salesforce from the Site User Profile. In that if Apex class has `url mapping' then you can access that class from a public site created in Salesforce.

like: https://restservice-developer-edition.eu2.force.com/services/apexrest/ifnamespace/accounts/0/contact?params=value

For the answer of using @HttpGet like annotations, You still require to specify the request method to be processed in an Apex rest class.

If a `GET` request is made, @httpGet annoted method will be invoked and there `RestContext` is available where you can get all request variables.

So similarly CORS can be added there using `RestContext`

ex:

```
RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
res.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://mydomain.force.com');
res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. 

I currently have this service exposed on a site, and if I use a browser extension (Chrome Rest Console) to pass data to it, it behaves correctly when calling the Http Post method. 

So you are saying that i should just add the above code (with the domain name or a wildcard) to the HttpPost Method and it will work? Will try.

Comment: here's what i have for now
 
`@HttpPost
    global static String submitSurvey(){
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        res.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
`
result:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://orientatio-cfa.cs8.force.com/portal/services/apexrest/surveydata. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.elearninginnovation.com' is therefore not allowed access. story.html?sfid=003L000000NIZPz&contextid=a0cL00000046IgR&resourceid=a0SL0000002df0r

Comment: I think i figured it out - the request is sending non form or text data (json) so it's preflighting, hence its not hitting the HttpPost but Options. I'll try to modify the sending info and see if this all works.

Comment: Turns out I was able to make this work. We kept the inbound calls meeting the W3C spec for "simple" CORS which avoided preflight. We then parse the origin against a set of known good domains and echo it back if it matches one of them. We pass unique key values determined by additional request parameters as an added measure of security (for now). 

All in all, nice option for what I thought was a dead end!

Comment: @AJD - any chance you could edit regal's answer a little, then accept it to show that you got it working?

Comment: Guess this speaks about the "simple" request:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS