# CORS APEX Rest Services

Tags: apex, apexrest, cors

How can I get my custom Apex Rest Services to use the CORS settings?

There are many similar questions like this [one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45724/can-we-hack-cors-support-for-custom-apex-rest-services-without-a-proxy); but these were asked before CORS was supported.

Comment: Please vote up this idea on salesforce so we can get cors in Custom apex rest services:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000lBEZAA2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated:**

As of the Summer '16 release CORS is available for Apex REST Classes. This is described in [Use CORS to Access Salesforce Resources from Web Browsers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/extend_code_cors.htm).

> These Salesforce technologies support CORS.
>
> - Analytics REST API
> - Bulk API
> - Chatter REST API
> - Salesforce IoT REST API
> - Lightning Out
> - REST API
> - User Interface API
> - Apex REST
>
> In Salesforce, add the origin serving the code to a CORS whitelist. If a browser that supports CORS makes a request to an origin in the whitelist, Salesforce returns the origin in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header, along with any additional CORS HTTP headers. If the origin is not included in the whitelist, Salesforce returns HTTP status code 403.
>
> 1. From Setup, enter CORS in the Quick Find box, then select CORS.
> 2. Select **New**.
> 3. Enter an origin URL pattern.
>      The origin URL pattern must include the HTTPS protocol (unless you’re using your localhost) and a domain name and can include a port. The wildcard character (*) is supported and must be in front of a second-level domain name. For example, https://*.example.com adds all subdomains of example.com to the whitelist.
>      The origin URL pattern can be an IP address. However, an IP address and a domain that resolve to the same address are not the same origin, and you must add them to the CORS whitelist as separate entries.

---

<s>Unfortunately at the moment CORS is still not available for custom REST endpoints. Spring '15 only made it available for the standard REST API.</s>

This is mentioned (incredibly briefly) at the end of [this Salesforce Developers Blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/spring-15-preview-cors-force-com-rest-api.html).

> Apex REST Methods are not accessible via CORS.

Fingers crossed they add it in a future release as this would solve some headaches in a couple of projects I'm working on.

Comment: How are you getting around this? Proxy?

Comment: Yes, currently we're forwarding all of our requests through a server side proxy. You can also set one up easily on Heroku using https://github.com/jamesward/sf-cors-proxy, although you'll have to modify conf/routes if you need to support anything other than GET and POST.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like Apex REST now supports CORS: http://blog.lkatney.com/2016/05/04/salesforces-summer-16-release-is-here/

> **Apex REST now supports CORS.**
>
> To access Apex REST classes from JavaScript in a web browser, add the origin that’s serving the script to the CORS whitelist. To add an origin to the CORS whitelist, from Setup, enter CORS in the Quick Find box, then select CORS. Click New, and then enter an origin URL pattern.

EDIT: Included relevant passages.

Comment: If your link answers the question, please quote the relevant passage(s). Also, if this feature was released in Summer 16, it should be in the relevant Release Notes document.

Answer (score 1):

As of Summer 16, Apex REST now supports CORS: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_rest_cors.htm